# Поясните работу mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, php, mod_rewrite

Передо мной закрытый хост у провайдера, который не хочет делиться секретами.

Имеется файл .htaccess следующего содержания:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc)$">
   Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo/

RewriteRule .* "index.php/?_p=$0" [L]
Options -Indexes
```

И файл index.php следующего содержания:

```
print_r(explode('/',$_GET['_p']));
```

Вроде бы все идеально работает, ЧПУ отвечает всем требованиям, поставленной задачи.

НО почему-то на запрос `/manual/` выдает `Array(0=>404.shtml)`?

Провайдер упорно намекает, что я лысый и шлет на доку по .htaccess

Подскажите мне мои ошибки. Еще момент: Почему-то интернал ерор выдается при отсутсвии в htaccess строк `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` и `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.

Comment: В проекте есть папка manual?

Comment: А корень сайта RewriteBase / ?

Comment: Хммм, я всегда использую **`$1`** o_O

Comment: Папки manual нет. Корень - это корень сайта.

Comment: Кстати, из тех поддержки посоветовали написать это:
    
    RewriteEngine Off

:))))))))
Начитал вот что:
If you have Apache installed on your system, there will likely be a copy of the Apache manual, right here, and the excellent mod_rewriting guide, lives right here. do check out the URL Rewriting Engine notes for the juicy syntax bits. That's where I got the cute quote for the top of the page, too.

Как это побороть в htaccess?

Comment: А все остальные запросы срабатывают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Папка **manual** обычно идет в апачевской сборке. Уж не она ли сюда примешивается?

Comment: Думаю да, надо ее в конфиге убирать специально, что не сделал хостер!)

Answer (score 1):

Отдельно прописать

```
    RewriteRule /manual "index.php/?_p=manual" [L]
```

Про мануал не знал. Спасибо.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но не работает. Я ее первой попробовал) Причем в разных вариациях...

Answer (score 1):

Хе-хе… У хостера явно в конфиге есть

```
AliasMatch ^/manual ...
```

куда-то там. То есть все запросы с путем, начинающимся с /manual, отправляются — не знаю, куда отправляются, это похоже на обрывок стандартного конфига, который отправляет такие запросы на документацию по апачу.

Проблема в том, что заменить alias на уровне файла .htaccess вы не можете, только на уровне настроек сервера или виртуал-хоста. Если хостер не предоставляет вам доступ к настройкам апача иначе как только в .htacess, то придется с ним договариваться. Увы.

Comment: Согласен, жаль ответ нельзя указать два правильных ответа!) Вам плюс, а автору выше ...